# Question about Compact metric space

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Please why $$\Delta_p=\lbrace (t_0,...,t_p)\in \mathbb{R}^{p+1},t_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=0}^p t_i=1\rbrace$$

is a compact metric space ?

Thank you

Comment: I would like to know that as well, for as far as I can tell, this is an unbounded set.

Comment: No i think that is a bounded set it is a convex hull !@HaraldHanche-Olsen

Comment: Well, it contains $(x,1-x,0‚\ldots,0)$ for *any* real $x$. That looks unbounded to me. Edit: I expect the condition $t_k\ge 0$ for $k=0,\ldots,p$ has been left out of the problem statement.

Comment: Why is bounded? $(-n, 0,...,0,n+1)$ is in your space. Are you thinking in $t_i\ge 0$ ??

Comment: Standard p-simplex is usually defined as $\Delta_p=\lbrace (t_0,...,t_p)\in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}, \sum_{i=0}^p t_i=1, t_i\geq 0, i=1,\dots p\rbrace$. Is this what you wanted to write? Then, it is compact.

Comment: @alans yes i edeted my question burt why it is a metric space ?

Comment: Any subset of a metric space is a metric space, by restricting the metric of the larger metric space – in this case, $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ – to the subset. Of course, the implicit assumed metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ must be the Euclidean metric: $d(x,y)=\sqrt{\sum_{j=0}^n|x_j-y_j|^2}$.

Comment: It's a closed subset of the compact set $[0,1]^{p+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Delta_p=\lbrace (t_0,...,t_p)\in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}, \sum_{i=0}^p t_i=1, t_i\geq0\rbrace$ is bounded since $0\leq t_i\leq 1$.

It's closed. Let $t_n=(t_0^n,...,t_p^n)\in \Delta_p$ s.t. $t_n\to t=(t_0,...,t_p)$. Then $1=\sum_{i=0}^p t_i^n\to \sum_{i=0}^p t_i=1$ and $t_i\geq 0$. So $t\in \Delta_p$. Hence it's closed.

Hence it's compact. And it's a metric space with induced metric from $\mathbb{R}^{p+1}$

Comment: and why metric space please ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Any subset of a metric space is a metric subspace with induced metric

Answer (score 0):

It is a hyperplane, right? Hence it is unbounded, hence not compact.

Comment: No, you have missed the restriction $t_i\geq 0$; and since the $\sum_i t_i=1$, none of the $t_i$ can exceed $1$.

Comment: True, I missed the restriction.

Comment: But then, indeed, $ 0 \leq t_i \leq 1 $ and hence $ \Delta_p$ is contained in the corresponding $p+1$-dimensional cube, thus bounded. And it is also the intersection of this cube wuth the hyperplane, both of which are closed. Hence, it is compact.

Comment: Indeed. Hence my comment on the original question. We are arriving at exactly the same conclusion, I think. :)

Comment: Exactly! Thanks.